# Complex layout with absolute positioning

Tags: css, css-position

I have to make a website that have this layout:
[image]

There are 4 blocks: green (the footer), blue (the sidebar), red (the main container), and orange (the content).

I'm finding some difficulties to center the elements. The red block have a fixed width and height (980x680) , the sidebar and the footer should remain in their place, and if I have a bigger screen they still have to fill the full width and the full height.

Do you think is it possible to accomplish this result?

Comment: It's absolutely possible. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Everything is possible, could you update a demo on http://jsfiddle.net/?

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this: http://www.sidekick.com.au/files/stackoverflow/div-positioning/

The height of the blue sidedbar is the only thing that needs work.  Currently it is set to a static height, or the height of whatever is inside it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this out... http://pixelsvsbytes.com/blog/2012/02/this-css-layout-grid-is-no-holy-grail/ or this one http://www.davidjrush.com/blog/2009/01/css-sticky-footer/